# i am new in programming .i am trying to make android app soundrecoder

Tags: android

I am trying to make an android application that can record audio and play them. 
for that, I made three button start, stop and play but my app crash
this is java code

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button play, stop, record;
    private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
    private String outputFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        record = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);


        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(false);

        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";
        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);


        record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                    myAudioRecorder.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ise", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ise.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ioe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
                record.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myAudioRecorder.stop();
                myAudioRecorder.release();
                myAudioRecorder = null;
                record.setEnabled(true);
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                play.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Recorder successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing Audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**stacktrace of crash**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
                                                                                  at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.arunjay.rtu.voiceofrtu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Are you running any other audio recording or playing app ?

Comment: no, sir when I would clicked the record button then the app got crashed and closed. but after searching I got the solution and that was really funny. the problem  was with the android version in android version marshmallow and above we need to explicitly  on the record audio setting from the setting and when i gave this permission problem was solved.thank you sir for your support and time.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: 
Make sure you set this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Step 2:
Ask for permission to record audio:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity(), 
Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
      BuildDev.RECORD_AUDIO);

} else {
   startRecording();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like permissions issue. Please try to place following code in `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";
        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

It might be case that you are initializing the `mediarecorder` before you have allowed permission.

Answer (score 1):

after searching I got the solution and that is really funny. the problem was with the android version in the android version marshmallow and above we need to explicitly on the record audio setting permission from the setting and when I gave this permission problem got solved. thank you all of you for your support and time.